# Data binding issue in MatTableDataSource with Array of Objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

As i am trying to bind the array of objects data to a MatTableDataSource but the table shows with empty results. I guess its a minor issue with data binding. I have written the code as below.

```
endPointsDataSource;
  endPointsLength;
  endPointsPage = 0;
  endPointsPageSize = 50;
  allProjectsEndpointsList = [];

  populateCoverage(objList) {
    let tObj = { resourceName: '', endpoints: [] }
    let cont = 1;
    let lastName = ''
    try {
      lastName = objList[0][4];
    } catch (e) { }
    tObj.resourceName = lastName;
    let resourceDefinitionList = [];
    objList.forEach(function (item) {
      let obj = { "projectName": item[6], "method": item[1], "endpoint": item[0], "description": item[3], "summary": item[4], "isManual": item[5] };
      if (lastName == item[4]) tObj.endpoints.push(obj);
      else if (lastName != item[4]) {
        resourceDefinitionList.push(tObj);
        tObj = { resourceName: item[4], endpoints: [obj] }; lastName = item[4]
      }
    });
    var arr: any = []
    arr = tObj;
    resourceDefinitionList.push(arr)
    return resourceDefinitionList;
  }

  showAllProjectsEndpoints() {
    this.resource.getAllProjectsEndpoints().subscribe((results) => {
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      if (this.handler.handle(results)) {
        return;
      }

      this.allProjectsEndpointsList = this.populateCoverage(results['data']);
      this.endPointsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.allProjectsEndpointsList);
    }, (error) => {
      this.handler.hideLoader();
      this.handler.error(error);
    });
  }
```

The html template code as follows:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 ">

                    <mat-table [dataSource]="endPointsDataSource">

                        <!-- projectName Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="projectName">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    {{element.projectName}}</mat-cell>

                            </mat-header-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- method Endpoint Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="method">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Endpoint
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.method}}</mat-cell>
                            </mat-header-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- endpoint Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="endpoint">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Endpoint
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.endpoint}}</mat-cell>
                            </mat-header-cell>
                        </ng-container>

                        <!-- description Column -->
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
                            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Description
                                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.description}}</mat-cell>
                            </mat-header-cell>
                        </ng-container>
                        
                        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="endPointsColumns"></mat-header-row>
                        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: endPointsColumns;"></mat-row>

                    </mat-table>

                    <mat-paginator [hidden]="vulnerabilityLength == 0" matColumnDef="position"
                        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [pageSize]="vulnerabilityPageSize"
                        [pageIndex]="vulnerabilityPage" (page)="changeVul($event)" [length]="vulnerabilityLength">
                    </mat-paginator>
                    
                </div>
```

Can anyone correct me what mistake i have made?

I am getting the empty table as below:
[image]

I am getting the data as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check your function `populateCoverage`. See that each element of your `allProjectsEndpointsList`array are in the way

```
{resourceName:...,endpoints:[...]}
```

So you need write some

```
{{elements.endpoints[0].description}}
```

TIP: Sometimes is util write in a td

```
{{element|json}}
```

To see the way of the element -obviously, the table crash-

Comment: Great.. Eliseo...